# Serial monitor garbage output on both MacOS and Windows devices, output used to make sense

Tags: esp8266

Baud rate is set to 115200 in both the serial monitor and in the setup() portion of the code. The output to the serial monitor just looks like a bunch of reverse question marks on MacOS and on Windows it's a bunch of gibberish characters. Any idea how to fix this and why it would have changed when the output used to be what I expected? Weird thing is the program on the board is still working because I'm seeing the proper output on my server but I want the serial monitor working for debugging if it's not making it to the server.

Comment: what else has changed?

Comment: Nothing that I've noticed. I don't think I even changed the code since this started happening.

Comment: plain esp8266 doesn't have USB. how do you connect it to Serial Monitor?

Comment: I have [this board](https://www.amazon.com/ESP8266-NodeMcu-Internet-Development-Micropython/dp/B07L8W9SP3/ref=sr_1_5?keywords=esp8266&qid=1560619324&s=gateway&sr=8-5) with a built on micro USB port.